# API call function example?

Tags: api, palantir-foundry

I want to call API with palantir workshop-action.
How to call API with palantir typescript function?
Any very simple examples?
thank you

Comment: you can't call external APIs via the typescript functions since they are sandboxed for security purposes.

Comment: You might be able to call another action that calls a webhook that calls an API.

Comment: Possible to provide a minimum reproducible example?